# Jquery multi to do list accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jquery accordion, java script and html5, trying to make it so that each section is a lists name.  Then within that section make so that you can add or remove from the list in that section. So you can see what I am doing [here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTLRE/2/).

I think the problem is here:

```
function add_listitem(key,item)
{
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    li.setAttribute("data-key,key");
    var but = document.createElement('button');
    but.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Delete'));
    but.onclick = remove_item;
    li.appendChild(but);
    document.getElementById('todo_list').appendChild(li);
}
```

It was working as just a single to-do list. Now however I can not seem to get it to work. Maybe I'm just to tired. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to assign the functions to an object.

[Here is a fiddle which attaches them to window](http://jsfiddle.net/WTLRE/4/) (not good) which fires the event.

I suggest you create a javascript object you can call the functions on

CODE:

```
 $('#add').click(function () {
     var listnames = prompt("Please enter list name", "List 1");
     $('#accordion').append('<h3><a href="#">' + listnames + '</a></h3><div id="' + listnames + '"><input onkeypress="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) window.add_items();" type="text" id="new_item" class="todo-input" placeholder="Add to list"></div>');
     $("#accordion").accordion('destroy').accordion();
 });
 window.add_items = function add_items(){
     //alert(this.document.activeElement.parentNode.id);
     var new_item = this.document.activeElement;
     alert(new_item.value);
     var key = new date();
```

Comment: I have to run it in fullscreen for it to work right [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WTLRE/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Ender `.accordion('destroy').accordion();` also seems a bit suspect to me. Check your html for validity (invalid markup will cause undefined behaviour)

Comment: Sorry I was talking about my code, and it only worked half the time. I will check on the .accordion('distroy') part. It has been a while since I have done this stuff. Now I just have to display it in a list below it.